# How can I fix this problem when connecting to VPS through Putty?

Tags: putty

I am getting this error when trying to connect to my Linode VPS using Putty:

Network error: Connection refused

Comment: sounds like you may either be connecting to the wrong host or on the wrong port. Connection is usually refused if a machine is up, but your trying to access it on the wrong port or your being firewalled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read through Linode's guide on connecting? http://library.linode.com/getting-started#sph_log-in-with-ssh-using-microsoft-windows

Failing that, have you tried the Lish console (which allows you to connect out-of-band when your Linode's networking is broken, so that you can go in and fix it)? http://library.linode.com/troubleshooting/using-lish-the-linode-shell

Comment: I can login ok with Lish, but I cannot connect with Putty. The port used is good as I double checked sshd_config

Comment: Did you ever resolve this one?  Just curious...

Answer (score 1):

Its possible your port 22 is not open. Please try opening it with terminal command "sudo ufw allow 22"